# Backup a Ruby in Rails app (Gitlab) with Cron job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, cron, gitlab

I tried ti backup my gitlab project (it's based on ROR) with a bash script triggered with a CRON job.

The bash script is ok except the rake migrations wiche returns an error:

> gitlabBackUp.sh: 12:
>   /home/backup/scripts/gitlabBackUp.sh: bundle: not found

Here is the way i did it in my gitlabBackUp.sh

```
# Export the data
bundle exec rake gitlab:backup:create --trace RAILS_ENV=production
```

I tried without the `bundle exec` but it returns

> /home/backup/scripts/gitlabBackUp.sh: 14:
>   /home/backup/scripts/gitlabBackUp.sh: rake: not found

Any tips?

**EDIT**:

I finally get the cron task get working with:

```
/usr/local/bin/bundle exec /usr/local/bin/rake gitlab:backup:create --trace RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: Are you using gitlab omnibus or a "hand" install gitlab? If you use omnibus, donc use `bundle exec rake gitlab:backup` but `gitlab-rake gitlab:backup`

Comment: The command `bundle exec rake gitlab:backup` works when i launch the script by hand, but i does not with CRON

Comment: Ok then check the `PATH` env var of the user who launch `CRON`: in my case, on old manual gitlab install, when calling `sudo bundle exec rake ...` it was working, but when as root I called `bundle exec rake...` it said `rake: not found`. The issue was that my `root` user didn't had ruby, bundle, gem & co in his `PATH`

Answer (score 1):

PATH is probably not well specified in cron. You can:

1) Call (exec) `bash` with `-l` e.g. `exec bash -l /path/to/real-script.sh`

Or perhaps directly in cron like `0 16 * * * /bin/bash -l '/home/backup/scripts/gitlabBackUp.sh'`

2) Explicitly specify path for bundle and rake e.g. `/usr/local/bin/bundle exec /usr/binrake gitlab:backup:create --trace RAILS_ENV=production`

You can always know the location of `bundle` and `rake` through `which bundle` and `which rake`; or `type -P bundle` and `type -P rake`.

Comment: Ok i put the path to absolute one. What is the `-l`for?

Comment: @angezanetti `-l` option of Bash makes it call Bash as if it's trying to log a user in and also makes it call startup files like /etc/profile, etc. Those files are needed to properly initialize variables including PATH.

Comment: OK, the con is owned by root, so do i need the `-l`?

Comment: See [Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) and [Invoking Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html).

Comment: @angezanetti Cron being owned by root doesn't affect the fact that it doesn't have initialized startup variables and that it doesn't export any to Bash. That's why you have to initialize Bash like a login session to summon those proper PATH values well.